# How to save attributedstring into Parse server Object type field

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsattributedstring

I am trying to save an attributed text into Parse server.
The field type is Object.

see the code

```swift
            let htmlData = try attributedText
                .data(from: NSRange(location: 0,
                                    length: attributedText.length),
                      documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
            // htmlData is Data type
            let note = PFObject(className:"Note")
            note["Data"] = htmlData
            note.saveEventually { (success, error) in
                if (success) {
                    // success is false
                }
            }
```

## I am getting this error

> schema mismatch for Note.Data; expected Object but got Bytes

Note: the *Note.Data* column type **Object**

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `htmlData` is a binary data representation of your attributed string. Binary data cannot be directly stored in the database as Parse Server does not support a Parse Object field of type [BLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object). You need a representation of the binary data which is compatible with a field type of Parse Server, like the `String` type.

You can convert the binary data into a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded `String` which is an ASCII representation, simply said, readable text:

```
// Create binary data from attributed text
let htmlData = try attributedText.data(
    from: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedText.length),
    documentAttributes: documentAttributes)

// Create string from binary data
let base64HtmlData = htmlData.base64EncodedData(options:[])

// Store string in Parse Object field of type `String`
let note = PFObject(className: "Note")
note["Data"] = base64HtmlData
```

You'd have to make sure in the Parse Dashboard that the type of your `Data` column is `String`.

However, keep in mind that large data should be stores in Parse Files, as Parse Objects are limited in size to [128 KB](https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#limits-and-other-considerations). Also, you don't want large data BLOBs in your MongoDB database as it will negatively impact performance when you scale.

Comment: Thanks. What if the htmlData usually contains images. still converting it to base64String a good idea? also, you mentioned using Parse File instead of base64String. is it using this way? note["Data"] = PFFileObject(data: htmlData) where Data column of type File

Comment: I corrected the answer. It should not matter if your attributed string contains images. The only issue I can think of is size. You can convert your `htmlData` into a `base64` string and calculate its required storage size, then make sure it is well below the 128kB size limit.